# How to activate page cache for Rails with Heroku & Cloudfront?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, browser-cache

A website analyzer says I don't have page cache activated, https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/bDj23F/www.anthonygalli.com. I followed every step I could get my hands on though. I'm using rails `"4.2.7.1"`

In the view

`<%= render :partial => @posts, cached: true %>`

In the controller

`fresh_when last_modified: @posts.created_at.utc, etag: @posts`

In production.rb

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'd37p52igaahgm9.cloudfront.net'
```

### UPDATE

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one thing you can do in your cloudfront distribution is to add a custom-header parameter.Here, [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching) and [Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#expiration-individual-objects) do not fully agree as Google recommends the use of `Expires` header and Amazon recommends the use of `Cache-Control max-age` parameter/value, so you must choose one as amazon will treat only `Cache-Control` if you specify the two

> We recommend that you use the Cache-Control max-age directive instead
>   of the Expires header field to control object caching. If you specify
>   values both for Cache-Control max-age and for Expires, CloudFront uses
>   only the value of Cache-Control max-age.

If your cloudfront distribution comes from a S3 bucket you can [Add Headers to Your Objects Using the Amazon S3 Console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationAddingHeadersInS3)

- Open the Properties of your s3 object from the aws s3 console
- In the right pane, expand Metadata.
- Click Add More Metadata.
- In the Key list, click Cache-Control or Expires, as applicable.
- In the Value field, enter the applicable value:

  - For a Cache-Control field, enter:

    ```
    max-age=number of seconds that you want objects to stay in a CloudFront edge cache
    ```
  - For an Expires field, enter a date and time in HTML format.
- Click Save.

See below in action

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! I can't find any mentioning of "metadata" in the properties section of my s3 bucket, maybe they discontinued that function? If you use s3 can you tell me if you found it for yourself?

Comment: sorry you need to go object by object (you cannot have the metadata applied for your all files at same time)

Comment: No worries, but did you find it object by object? I did didn't see an option for "metadata" there either.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com adding a screenshot for the key metadata

Comment: Thank you! Okay that could be part of the problem then I'll add screenshot.

Comment: If I then click "standard" and "save" then refresh the page it just shows the same page again.

Comment: standard is your type of storage, it does not impact the http header field, you need to go to the file level, not the bucker nor the folder, you really need to go deep down to the (css/js) file itself

Comment: Sorry I really don't know what you mean by "go deep down to the (css/js) file. Do I add a line of code those application files?

Comment: you need to browse your S3 bucket and select the css/js files - open the properties tab and then you will be able to add the metadata tag for the specific file

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, there are three type of cashing in rails

- Page Caching => For all page to put in cache.. mostly used for
  static pages
- Action Caching => Top put a controllers action
- Fragment Caching =>  For A part of view/ or for a logic etc

Also necessary to implement observers and sweeper to expire cache on some changes/conditions, otherwise same will be render again n again